# I have some reservations about reservations

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice, vocabulary, indian-english

> **The Indian constitution provided  reservations to  some weaker  sections in the society**.

Once  I used the sentence on Linked In and  an English  scholar  said that  the use of **reservations** in the sentence is wrong and  I went on explaining  its meaning. He understood the word in the sense of  **doubt**

India is a country of reservations like  **women's reservation bill**. In India  there are reservations for  the  scheduled castes, backward  castes, physically  handicapped. Even  women are fighting  for  reservations  in  the  parliament. The bill has been  pending  because of male  dominance. Reservations  means special  priveleges  provided  to some  sections of  people  because  of  birth, gender, handicap etc.

I would like to know whether the usage in the above sentence is right or wrong.

If it is wrong,  what  is  the  proper word here?

I herewith provide the link too.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reservation

I have  provided the Wikipedia too

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservation_in_India

https://indconlawphil.wordpress.com/tag/reservations/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes, it's correct—in India

When I first read your sentence, I thought that it misused the word **reservations**. But I was wrong. I am an American native speaker, and I just did some googling and learned that the sense of "reservations" in your sentence is standard in India but not in Britain or America. It is not mentioned in the Merriam-Webster article that you linked to, though there are some closely related senses.

Outside of India, the closest word for this sense of "reservations" is **quotas**. But even the word "quota" is ambiguous. The relevant sense is the third listed by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quota). But there are common senses of "quota" not listed by Merriam-Webster, that have the opposite meaning, such as a goal for a quantity of something to be produced (as in "meet your quota") or even a maximum quantity of something that you are permitted to consume (as in "exceed your quota"). See [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quota#English). You could not use the word "quotas" for India's constitutional reservations without explaining it and expect to be understood.

### You might need to explain it

As always, Know Your Audience. If the audience for your writing is people from India, then your use of **reservations** is correct, standard, and needs no explanation. If you are writing for people in Britain or America, then you should still use the word "reservations"—no other word will do—but you must explain it, just as you would explain any specialized or esoteric terminology when writing for a general audience. [This article](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-34082770) by the British Broadcasting Corporation illustrates how to do it:

> India's constitution, adopted in 1950, inaugurated the world's oldest and farthest-reaching affirmative action programme, guaranteeing scheduled castes and tribes—the most disadvantaged groups in Hinduism's hierarchy—not only equality of opportunity but guaranteed outcomes, with **reserved** places in educational institutions, government jobs and even seats in parliament and the state assemblies.
>
> These "**reservations**" or **quotas** were granted to groups on the basis of their (presumably immutable) caste identities. The logic of reservations in India was simple: they were justified as a means of making up for millennia of discrimination based on birth.

After this definition, the article freely uses the word **reservations** in the sense that you have in mind. The reader can now be expected to understand when "reservations" denotes this new concept.

In this context, the quotation marks around **reservations** help indicate that the author does not expect the reader to already know this sense of the word, and is now defining it. Putting the word in italics is another way to indicate that you are defining a new word or a new sense of a familiar word. Notice also that the article provides some background information before defining the term and states the rationale for the reservations. This makes the definition easier to understand. The background paragraph even uses the word **reserved**, which helps the reader see why the word "reservations" was chosen.

### More sources of confusion

By the way, this word will be especially prone to confusion in America, where **an Indian reservation** means a [land area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_reservation) reserved to native Americans, where they enjoy rights similar to those of an independent nation. So, you should not use the phrase "Indian reservation" to refer to the distinctively Indian sense of "reservation".

Lastly, **weaker sections** is suggestive but not clear. The phrase **disadvantaged groups** makes clear what kind of people reservations in India are intended to benefit, without going into detail about the castes and social classes.

Answer (score 0):

Your use is technically correct, but the meaning of "reservations" is totally ambiguous.  In your sentence, it could mean doubt, a plot of land, a scheduled meeting, or something set aside for someone else.

The context of the sentence may help provide clues to your meaning, but it is better to avoid using overloaded words if the meaning is not immediately clear.

You could say:

> The constitution **causes doubt among** weaker sections...
>
> The constitution **provides special services** to weaker sections...
>
> The constitution **sets aside land for** weaker sections...
>
> The constitution **allots times or positions specifically for** weaker sections...

Comment: The  constitution  causes doubt  among  weaker sections  may  have  negative  connotations. Indians  usually  the  constitution  provided or  guarenteed  reservations  to  weaker  sections.Even  the  constitution  says  that.Dr Ambedkar  was  a great scholar who  drafted  the  constitution

Comment: If your response is you adding additional context, then I ask that you edit it into your original question.

Answer (score 0):

I think, from what you say, that in India 'reservations' has a special, local meaning, when applied to government.

I think the word you need, to use instead, to convey this meaning in English when speaking to people from other countries, is 'concessions', which means 'special adjustments or allowances' (made to any particular group, eg. women.

I think that will eliminate the confusion.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/concession

Comment: The word reservation is a nationalised  word.No word  can substitute that  in India.

Comment: Oh, I thought you had asked about using the word 'with an English scholar'.  And you went on to say 'I would like to know whether the usage in the above sentence is right or wrong.  If it is wrong, what is the proper word here?'. So I think you'd better define where you mean by 'here'. Because if the answer to 'here' is 'India' then the answer to that appears to be 'reservations'. So then I am wondering, what are you asking, exactly?

Comment: I talked to the English Scholar.I do not say that is right.Bur Indians are accustomed to the usage.

Comment: So, what are you asking, exactly?